# How to prevent double encoding of query string httpclient?

Tags: c#, encoding, httpclient, unicode-string

I have query string with unicode characters, for ex. "`http://api.test.com?q=Túls Engeniería`".

I send this query string in get request, `BuildUrl` method returns encoded string - `httpclient.GetAsync("http://api.test.com?q=T%u00fals+Engenier%u00eda")`, but in the request that I see in fiddler query is encoded additionally - "`http://api.test.com?q=T%25u00fals+Engenier%25u00eda`", How can I prevent this double encoding?

```
private async Task<string> MakeGetCall(string apiVersion, string url, string accessToken, NameValueCollection urlParameters = null)
{
    var client = GetHttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_VALUE_CONST_PART, accessToken);

    var result = await client.GetAsync(BuildUrl(apiVersion + url, urlParameters));
    result.EnsureSuccess();

    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

private string BuildUrl(string baseUrl, NameValueCollection urlParameters)
{
    string finalUrl = baseUrl;

     if (urlParameters != null)
     {
         var builder = new UriBuilder(string.Empty, baseUrl);
         var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);

         query.Add(urlParameters);

         builder.Query = query.ToString();
         finalUrl = builder.ToString();
     }

     return finalUrl;
 }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you create and send request?

Comment: updated question